# Anjuta Failure when Building Configuration

Tags: anjuta

I have successfully installed Anjuta, defined a project using existing source files, and successfully compiled and linked it using the 'default' configuration.

When I try to build the 'debug' configuration (and any other configuration), the build fails. The first message that I think is relevant is:

```
/home/dave/Code/ww_index/configure CFLAGS=-g -O0 CXXFLAGS=-g -O0 JFLAGS=-g -O0 FFLAGS=-g -O0"
```

I then get a few 'checking' messages (all responses look OK - no errors are reported) but the build fails with this message:

```
configure: error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first
```

I have tried the `make distclean` in the `ww_index/src` directory and this is successful but wipes out the executable and the 'Make...' files.

There are no other directories defined under 'Debug'. I only see a `config.log` file there with expanded messages that were also shown in the console as a result of my action.

What do I need to do to Anjuta to have it successfully build other configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `make distclean` will delete the executable and the `Makefile` and `Makefile.in`, both in the `src` and in the root directory of your project. That's fine. If you do a `./configure` in the root directory, the `Makefile*` files should be re-generated.

```
configure CFLAGS=-g -O0 CXXFLAGS=-g -O0
```

I think there should be ' (single quotes) around each of the option groups like this:

```
configure 'CFLAGS=-g -O0' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O0' ...
```

but that might be a problem of posting it here. Check for the quotes in Build | Configure Project window.

Try typing `autoreconf`, and then `automake` in the terminal window while in the project's root directory, and report any strange messages.